# How does Memgraph work with Kafka streams?

Tags: memgraphdb

Does Memgraph act as a sink for streaming sources from Kafka, and then once the messages have been received, organize them into a graph database? If yes, how are these messages being organized. I don't get how the messages can be transformed from the format they are in a certain topic to the something that is understandable to the graph database such as Memgraph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Memgraph is consuming messages from Kafka with its internal consumer. This means that you need to [create a stream](https://memgraph.com/docs/memgraph/import-data/data-streams/manage-streams#create-a-stream-in-memgraph) inside Memgraph and define from which topic data will be read. Before doing that, you have to [create and load a transformation module](https://memgraph.com/docs/memgraph/import-data/data-streams/manage-streams#create-and-load-a-transformation-module-into-memgraph) for a certain stream. [Transformation module](https://memgraph.com/docs/memgraph/reference-guide/streams/transformation-modules) is a procedure that tells Memgraph how to transform Kafka messages to Cypher queries which will be executed for each consumed message. Once you create a stream, you have to [start a stream](https://memgraph.com/docs/memgraph/import-data/data-streams/manage-streams#start-ingesting-data-from-the-stream) to start ingesting data from the stream. Because of the transformation module, the data from your Kafka topic will seamlessly be stored into the graph database.